# "This chapter has been divided into two sections, those are/which are/such that children and adults."

Tags: sentence-construction

Among these sentences, which one would be ideal when introducing a list

> This chapter has been divided into two sections, **those are** children and adults.

> This chapter has been divided into two sections, **which are** children and adults.

> This chapter has been divided into two sections **such that** children and adults.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these the names of the sections, or are you just describing the contents?

If you are describing the contents of the sections, you could say:

- This chapter has been divided into two sections, about children and adults respectively.
- This chapter has been divided into two sections, relating to children and adults respectively.
- This chapter has been divided into two sections, concerning children and adults respectively.
- This chapter has been divided into two sections: one about children, the other about adults.

If you are naming the sections, you should capitalise them (and perhaps use either quotation marks or italics to make things clearer):

- This chapter has been divided into two sections, namely *Children* and *Adults*.
- This chapter has been divided into two sections: *Children* and *Adults*.
- This chapter has been divided into two sections; these are *Children* and *Adults*. --*This is the closest thing to your "those are" sentence, although I prefer my other two suggestions above.*

Your suggestions have a few problems:

- This chapter has been divided into two sections, those are children and adults. -- *Try to avoid using a comma to join two independent sentences, especially in formal work.  Also, "Those" doesn't work well here*
- This chapter has been divided into two sections, which are children and adults. -- *This could work if the section names were capitalised, but it doesn't read well.*
- This chapter has been divided into two sections such that children and adults. -- *This is ungrammatical.*

Comment: Thanks a lot, rjpond for your wonderful explanation. it really helps me..!